# Find all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f\big(yf(x)\big)=x^2y^4$

Tags: functional-equations

It's my last question. Just give me advice how to start.

> Find all such functions
> $$f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\text,$$
> for all real $x$ and $y$, the equality
> $$f\big(yf(x)\big)=x^2y^4$$

Comment: are the function continuous ? derivable ?

Comment: Show that f(1) is not 0.

Comment: Function are contimuos.

Answer (score 1):

$
f(yf(1))=y^4,
$
so $f(1)\ne0$, so $f(y)=\left(\frac{y}{f(1)}\right)^4$. Now putting $y=1$ in last equation we get $f(1)=1$ and $f(y)=y^4$. Now it is easy too see that $f(y)=y^4$ cannot satisfy the equation $f(yf(x))=x^2y^4$

Comment: why is The first sentence true?

Comment: Which part do you mean?

Comment: The first sentence of your answer.

Comment: There are 3 formulas in the first sentence. Which of them don't you agree with?

Comment: The third one I dont understant.

Comment: @PedroArbizu Putting $x=1$ in $f(yf(x))=x^2y^4$, we get $f(yf(1))=y^4$. If $f(1)=0$ this would mean $f(0)=y^4$ for all $y$, so $y^4$ is a constant, which is absurd; so $f(1)\ne0$. Replace $y$ with $y/f(1)$ in $f(yf(1))=y^4$.

Comment: I understand now. I had to use some paper to see. Maybe, just to make it more understanble for the OP, you should do $z = y f(1) $. and then change $z$ for $y$. (+1). Apologies for being slow.

Comment: Putting $y=1$ in $f(y)=(y/f(1))^4$ we get $f(1)^5=1$, so $f(1)=1$ since $f$ is assumed to be real-valued. Could there be complex-valued solutions?

Comment: This is a bad answer to the question asked, which was for a start.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but:

In the case $y=1$, we get $f(f(x)) = x^2$, so $f(x)$, it it exists at all, must equal $x^\sqrt{2}$ for all possible $x$

But now we run into trouble as $f(x):=x^{\sqrt{2}}$ does not satisfy that property for y $\neq 1$. Indeed, $f(yf(x)) = y^\sqrt{2} x^2$