# Finding function(s) $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ which satisfies $f(xf(y))=x^2y^3.$ (Proof verification)

Tags: solution-verification, functional-equations

> $f: \mathbb{R^+} \to \mathbb{R^+}$ which satisfies $f(xf(y))=x^2y^3.$

\begin{align}
& \text{let } P(x, y): f(xf(y))=x^2y^3. \\
\ \\
P(1, x): \; & f(f(x))=x^3. \\
\ \\
P(f(x), y): \; & f(f(x)f(y))=f(x)^2y^3. \\
\therefore \; & f(f(x)f(y))=x^3f(y)^2. \\
\Rightarrow \; & f(x)^2y^3=x^3f(y)^2. \\
& \dfrac{f(x)^2}{x^3}=\dfrac{f(y)^2}{y^3}. \\
\therefore \; & f(x)=kx^{\frac {3} {2}}. \\
\ \\
&f(f(x))=k\left(kx^{\frac {3} {2}}\right)^{\frac {3} {2}}=k^{\frac {5} {2}} x^3 = x^3. \\
\therefore \; & k=1, f(x)=x^{\frac {3} {2}}. \\
\ \\
\end{align}

But, putting this to the original FE, we get the contradiction. Did I prove that there doesn't exist any function $f$ that satisfies the above? If not, did I miss something?

Linked question: [Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(yf(x))=x^2y^4.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033414/find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-such-that-f-bigyfx-big-x2y4?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: A [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033414/find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-such-that-f-bigyfx-big-x2y4?noredirect=1) here which has no solution, and uses the suggested path. It seems you have done all the right things and there is no solution to your question as well

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Oh, thanks. So, I did prove that there doesn't exist and function $f$ satisfies the condition. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome, although (post facto) I do wonder how to answer this question, after all it seems to be done and dusted following that comment.

Comment: Maybe I have to answer myself with a community wiki and make it the checked answer.

Comment: Good idea, you can do that with my comment if necessary. Do attach the "linked question", because it's a similar question that hints at your work being "verified" by others working the same way as well.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Alright, I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll have to go now (to another question!) but +1 from my side for the nice question and community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the verification was done at the comment, I'll put this as an answer with the community wiki.